# Simplify is not simplifying a compound inequality as expected

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic, assumptions

The `Simplify` command is having trouble verifying a compound inequality, even while it correctly handles the two corresponding single inequalities.

I'm starting with some simple global assumptions:

`$Assumptions = Element[k, Integers] && i == k + 1;`

Under these assumptions, the following uses of `Simplify` all return `True`, as expected:

```
In[2]:= Simplify[i == k + 1]
Out[2]= True

In[3]:= Simplify[k < k + 1 < k + 2]
Out[3]= True

In[4]:= Simplify[k < i && i < k + 2]
Out[4]= True
```

**However**, combining the two inequalities from the last input above into one compound inequality does not yield the expected output:

```
In[5]:= Simplify[k < i < k + 2]
Out[5]= k < i < 2 + k
(*NOT True as expected*)
```

Why does `Simplify`not recognize that this compound inequality is true?

(Note: I realize it seems silly to check if `k<i<k+2` since I'm already assuming `i=k+1`. However, I was having problems while dealing with more complex code, and this behavior of `Simplify` seemed to be at the root of it.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Something I've noted about Mathematica, is it is best to be complete in defining variable domains. Also define `i` as an integer, which you might think it implicitly is from your definition `i == k + 1`:

```
$Assumptions = {i, k} ∈ Integers && i == k + 1;
```

Then try your code

```
Simplify[k < i < k + 2]
(* True *)
```

Curious to see if that fixes your bigger problem.

Comment: Thanks!  That does fix the issue I was having!